# Assign object the return value of boost::lambda::bind?

Tags: c++, boost-lambda

I would think it could be useful to store a bound lambda function to be used later, yet I haven't seen any examples on the return value of the `boost::lambda::bind` function being assigned to an object of that return type.  Is there no way to do this cleanly, or is there just no reason to do it?

Example:

```
boost::lambda::lambda_functor<?> lf = boost::lambda::bind(boost::lambda::constructor<Foo>(), x);
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Boost.Lambda, but in C++11, you can use `auto`

Comment: If you're already using C++11, there isn't a great need for boost::lambda; lambdas are already part of the language in C++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use boost.Function to store function objects:

```
boost::function<Foo()> lf = boost::lambda::bind(boost::lambda::constructor<Foo>(), x);
```